# New to hashcode and need help understanding code snippet

Tags: java

I have the following code snippet and need some help understanding a few pieces of it.

```
String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

int hashcode = fileName.hashCode();

//I'm not sure why we are creating a mask with an int of 255
int mask = 255;

//Wny are we adding 255 to the hashcode?
int firstDir = hashcode & mask;

//What does it mean to have (hashcode >> 8) & mask? If I were to build a third
// tier would I use (hashcode >> 16) $ mask?
int secondDir = (hashcode >> 8) & mask;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(File.separator);

//I noticed when using this %02 it truncates the directory to 2 chars, does this 
//just convert 3 digits to alpha numeric representing the same three digits?
sb.append(String.format("%02x", firstDir));

sb.append(File.separator);
sb.append(String.format("%02x", secondDir));
sb.append(File.separator);
```

Lastly, if I wanted to generate a file name from the two directories, would I just setup another string builder without the File.separator, or would it be more efficient to build the string first without the file separator, then split up the string?

Comment: First go and read about the `&` and `>>` operators.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and also about hex and format strings!

Comment: `&` (AND) is a [bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) - do some reading and understand **exactly** how they work before trying to use them.

Comment: I agree with you all, I did do a google search can came up with garbage which is the reason for resorting to here for additional help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

255 is 0FF hex, 0 1111 1111 binary.

A mask used with the 'and' operator ("&") is used to isolate the bits of the value to which the mask is anded -- an integer anded with the above mask results in an integer with the same lowest-order 8 bits as the original integer.

An integer put through >> 8 is shifted to the right 8 bits; anding with the same mask after that isolates those 8 bits, which started out as the next-higher-order 8 bits in the original integer.

Don't worry about efficiency unless you can show that a few microseconds is going to make a difference.  Worry about making your code understandable enough that someone doesn't have to post to stackoverflow to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

That code is just silly.

If you want to create two randomly distributed two-digit hex codes derived from a random UUID, you can just use the first four hex digits of the UUID itself.

```
String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String firstDir = fileName.substring(0,2);
String secondDir = fileName.substring(2,4);
```

A random UUID is a cryptographically strong random binary string (except for [a few fixed digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Version_4_.28random.29) to denote that this is a type-4 UUID). Any hashing and bit shifting or masking will just degrade the randomness.

Comment: using your suggested logic, would this still allow for a maximum of 1000 items per directory?

Comment: It would be 256 in both cases for the hashed directory layers. 00 to FF. The number of files under, say, `12/34/` is potentially unlimited (but unlikely to reach a very high number). Same as with your original code.

Comment: I think I'm going to use your solution, it seems much simpler than the above code which I found online. I have one last question, I just did a test to test file distribution with a million files and never once did I see 2 files in the same directory using something like this. \9d\62\f35a.jpg. Is there a chance you could throw the balance off with to many directories causing performance issues?

Comment: Two layers of intermediate directories may be overkill. Maybe one is enough for your purposes. But performance impact should be negligible. Definitely better than with not having these directories. But with a million files you must have a directory with at least two files: 255 * 255 is less than one million.

Comment: Thanks Thilo, I have to mark rcook as the best answer since he answered my original question, but I'm using your solution since it seems to be a much cleaner solution to my original problem.